# No node found for selector in (Puppeteer Error)

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, automation, puppeteer

This is the code I have given:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
    const baseUrl = 'example.com';
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true});
    const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();

    function delay(time) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            setTimeout(resolve, time)
        });
    }

    await page.goto(baseUrl);

    await page.waitForSelector('[name="loginfmt"]');
    await page.type('[name="loginfmt"]', 'abc@amazon.com');
    await page.click('[type="submit"]');
    delay(1000);
    await page.authenticate({ username: `abc@amazon.com`, password: `abc@123` });

    await page.click((`[data-row-id="111-222-333-444"]`));
    await delay(1000);

    await page.pdf(
        {
            path: "Z1.pdf",
            printBackground: true,
            width: '1300px',
            height: '14200px'
        }
    )

    browser.close();
})()
```

When inspected the page with document.querySelectorAll(`[data-row-id="111-222-333-444"]`); it returned a `NodeList` array which consisted the details which I have been looking for.
However when tried the same via Puppeteer it terminates with an error saying "Error: No node found for selector: [data-row-id="111-222-333-444"]"

Tried using:
"const button= await page.$((`[data-row-id="111-222-333-444"]`);
button.click();"

I have been trying to fix this since a long time. It would be really helpful if I get a fix for this.

Comment: May the element be inside an iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
    const baseUrl = 'example.com';
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true});
    const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();
 

    await page.goto(baseUrl);

    await page.waitForSelector('[name="loginfmt"]');
    await page.type('[name="loginfmt"]', 'abc@amazon.com');
    await page.click('[type="submit"]');
    await page.waitForTimeout(1000) 
    await page.authenticate({ username: `abc@amazon.com`, password: `abc@123` });

    await page.waitForTimeout(5000) 

    await page.$(`[data-row-id="111-222-333-444"]`);

    await page.click((`[data-row-id="111-222-333-444"]`));
    await page.waitForTimeout(1000) 

    await page.pdf(
        {
            path: "Z1.pdf",
            printBackground: true,
            width: '1300px',
            height: '14200px'
        }
    )

    browser.close();
})()
```

Comment: Tried executing the same code as mentioned by you but have encountered the below error.


`(node:17748) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation.`
 
   
`(node:17748) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().`

Comment: The first error I can see is that baseUrl doesn't use the real domain where you are trying to do the request.

Also the url <string> URL to navigate page to. The URL should include scheme, e.g. https://

https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v9.1.1&show=api-pagegotourl-options

Comment: Since the URL which I am using is a sensitive information, I haven't posted up here regarding it. But when I am trying it from my end I have replaced it with a real domain URL.

Comment: I suggest you start using headless: false and without createIncognitoBrowserContext and when you have all working change it. It will help you to debug and see errors easily. Also use try catch where you are using await. For me is very difficult to provide more answers without a real URL to test my code.

Comment: Have tested it in headful mode but I was able to just reach that page and can't click that selector.

Comment: Could you provide an HTML page with the code?